# How to install eclipse i have set my class path for JDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

![Myscreenshot][1]

please guys tell me how to install Eclipse because I have set my class paths for JDK( both javac and java) but still i am facing error. Do I have to set eclips's path too if so then how? If there are some other ways then please let me know. Thanks all

Comment: Isn't eclipse just a zip file which you can extract wherever you like, and simply start the .exe? That's all I had to do. Your screenshot looks great btw.

Comment: Hint: use the number and letter keys on your computer keyboard to enter text describing what actually happens.  You don't have enough rep to link to screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a portable application, so you don't need to install it like the other app (such as you installing WinRAR.exe on your PC). You just need to place the [eclipse's file name that you downloaded].zip into a folder or a path. Example--> "D:\Eclipse\your zip file goes here". Extract the zip here and open a file named eclipse.exe. To use eclipse in java language, install JDK and JRE.